# How do you correctly write this sentence as a CTL formula?

Tags: logic, model-checking, temporal-logic, computation-tree-logic

Sentence: From every reachable state it is possible to reach a state where $p$ is true.

How do you write this sentence as a CTL formula? So far I only dealt with CTL syntax and trees but maybe it will also be asked in a test how you convert a sentence to a CTL formula..

So I've read that $AX$ means *all next*.

Then $AXp$ should mean *in all next states $p$ is true*.

Now I only need the first part of the sentence: *From every reachable state it is possible to reach*

But how would this be expressed and how do you connect it with the $AXp$ I got?

I hope you can help me because on the internet I couldn't find some example like that? : /

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can learn a lot about CTL at Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_tree_logic).

The sentence you need to write, expressed more closely in the vocabulary of CTL operators, would be
*Along all paths starting from current state, it always has to hold that there exists at least one path where $p$ eventually is true.*

I think you can take it from there, but comment if you have troubles.

---

**hint:** The operators you will need to use are $F$, $A$, $E$ and $G$.

Comment: Thank you very much for help! Then I think the answer is $AGEFp$? If that's correct, I'm still not sure about the syntax. Can I write it like that?

Comment: It is correct. If you are sometimes not sure, you can always (edit: maybe not always, depending on strictness of a language) use additional parentheses, giving you A(G(E(Fp))).

Comment: Glad to hear, thanks so much :D

Just another example I found, maybe you can check if I did it correct: "In all paths you sometime/eventually reach a state where it's possible that $p$ is always true in future."

I think "in all paths" means $AG$, "sometime/eventually reach a state" is $F$, "where it's possible that" is $E$. So in total that should be $AGFEp$?

Comment: Your understood it pretty good, but missed the last part - “...is ALWAYS true in future” - which requires a $G$. So we have $AGFEGp$.